# How to create login session in cmd via username and password on web form

Tags: authentication, heroku, command-line-interface

I want to create a console application similar to Heroku / Google cloud CLI tool that routs the user to the default web login form. Once the user is validated on the browser the session is passes to the CMD terminal. How does it work ? In the below screenshot i used heroku cli , when i type `heroku login` I am presented with a browser form.

[image]

Comment: Just want to know what the process is called

Comment: https://community.auth0.com/t/example-of-cli-login-through-web-browser-in-node/61507

Comment: https://hasinthaindrajee.medium.com/browser-sso-for-cli-applications-b0be743fa656

Comment: above links are solution reference from the internet